# Can rEFInd use High Sierra's apfs.efi driver?

Tags: macos, boot, drivers, macos-highsierra, refind

I recently was helping another user install rEFInd on a MacBook Pro 2018. See the question: [Bless error when installing rEFInd](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/338574/bless-error-when-installing-refind). While the other user now reports successfully using rEFInd to boot High Sierra from a APFS volume, I am left will questions regarding some the necessary installation steps. The other user reports needing to copy a `apfs.efi` driver from High Sierra to rEFInd's `drivers_x64` folder. The other users also states that rEFInd did detect macOS **without** this driver, but could **only** boot to macOS when this driver was copied. So, my two most pressing questions are list below.

1. Does rEFInd really use this driver?
2. If rEFInd has already found a possible macOS EFI boot file, then why would rEFInd need a read from the APFS volume in order to instruct the firmware to boot using the found file? I assume the drivers are only used to find EFI boot files and that rEFInd does not actually load the files.

Comment: Perhaps it's not rEFInd itself but the "macOS EFI boot file" which needs to read further data (...such as the actual macOS kernel) from the APFS volume?